# Using Vuetify with i18n using CDNs only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I'm working on a Vue project on a static environment with no Node or Vue-cli,
We're importing Vue, Vuetify and vue-i18n using CDNs

We need to have the Vuetify components translated using the Vue-i18n like shown [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#vue-i18n)

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/7uP/pen/JQXbWG) of an attempt i've made, trying to translate the pagination part at the bottom.

I've tried using `Vue.use()` but couldn't get it to work, no errors in the console and no translation on the page.

```js
import App from '../components/App.vue.js';
import i18n from '../lang/languages.js';
import store from './store/store.js';

Vue.filter('toUpperCase', function(value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
});

Vue.config.devtools = true;

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  lang: {
    t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params)
  }
});

new Vue({
  i18n,
  store,
  el: '#app',
  render: (h) => h(App)
});
```

lang/languages.js:

```js
import { russian } from './languages/russian.js';
import { chineseSimple } from './languages/chinese-simple.js';
import { german } from './languages/german.js';
import { portuguese} from './languages/portuguese.js';

const languages = {
  'ru': russian,
  'zh-Hans': chineseSimple,
  'de': german,
  'pt': portuguese,
};

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages: languages
});

export default i18n;
```

Comment: You can check out this example: https://codepen.io/vsco/pen/MrrgbO
He got it working, I know it's a very simple example. But I'm sure you get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not available in `CDN` distributions. You might ask why?

Look at this [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/9f47fe560b73173b07527d4fbb7051b4300fae28/packages/vuetify/src/index.ts#L19):

```
const Vuetify: VuetifyPlugin = {
  install (Vue: VueConstructor, args?: VuetifyUseOptions): void {
    Vue.use(VuetifyComponent, {
      components,
      directives,
      ...args
    })
  },
  version: __VUETIFY_VERSION__
}

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Vue) {
  window.Vue.use(Vuetify)
}
```

Especially this part:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Vue) {
  window.Vue.use(Vuetify)
}
```

It automatically installs the Vuetify without any configurations such as language and etc, so your `Vue.use(Vuetify, {..})` won't get called because [Vue won't install plugins twice](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/6fe07ebf5ab3fea1860c59fe7cdd2ec1b760f9b0/src/core/global-api/use.js#L8)!

What you could do?

1. Clone the Vuetify repo and change this part of the code and build a new dist for your self.
2. Save as the file `vuetify.dist.js` and change that part of the code
3. Use some hacky tricky workarounds which I don't recommend, but I created a sample for you.

Here is a code pen [example](https://codepen.io/al1b/pen/QXQdqz), What I actually do:

1. Load Vue.js file with scripts tag
2. Use fetch api to download content of `vuetify.dist.min.js`
3. Replace `window.Vue` to something else to make sure `vuetify` won't install itself automatically!
4. Eval the changed code

**I DON'T RECOMMEND THIS APPROACH AT ALL**

```
fetch("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.js")
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(vutify => {
    eval(vutify.replace("window.Vue", "window.Vue2"));

    Vue.use(Vuetify, {
      lang: {
        t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params)
      }
    });

    const App = Vue.component("app", {
      template: `
```

Comment: I was told that this i being fixed for Vuetify 2.0
Unfortunatly we don't have the time to wait for it and we may need to try your solution... Thanks!

Comment: @ZimGil Thanks to them, My solution works, you can try it in the codepen I provided. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it works for you.

Comment: I need to find some time for it and I guess only next week I will be able to try it, I will update and of course mark as accepted if it will work :)

Comment: As we use a pre-downloaded CDN (out product is not connected to the Internet) - I was able to acieve this by hard changing the CDN code like it would happen in `vutify.replace("window.Vue", "window.Vue2")` and it seems to work... 
Not ideal but will do for now until 2.0... THANKS!